# Complex SQL query to get outputs from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using information from multiple tables to try and get the output to be, Supplier ID, Supplier Name, Percent of orders with tracking number.

I need information from many tables, as follows:

- Suppliers, this contains supplier ID and supplier name
- SupplierSubscriptions, the supplier must have subscriptionid = 91, this contains supplier id.
- SalesOrders, this contains each order for every supplier, so it contains supplier id.
- Shipments, this contains the salesorder id, with each shipment associated to that order.
- Packages, this contains the shipmentid and if the shipment is on the packages table, it contains a tracking number.

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.supplierID, count(*) AS NumberOfOrders FROM SalesOrders so 
INNER JOIN suppliers s ON s.SupplierID = so.SupplierID
INNER JOIN SupplierSubscriptions ss ON s.SupplierID = ss.SupplierID
INNER JOIN shipments ship ON ship.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Packages p ON p.ShipmentID = ship.ShipmentID
WHERE ss.SubscriptionID = 91 GROUP BY so.SupplierID
```

this, obviously, is not what I am after, as it only shows the supplier id and a count of orders...

Comment: Can you post the table structure? It's easier that way. You can take a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing on parts of the schema, but something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT      so.supplierID,
            so.supplierName,
            SUM(case when p.trackingNumber is not null then 1 else 0 end) / COUNT(0) as OrdersWithTracking
FROM        SalesOrders             so 
INNER JOIN  suppliers               s       ON s.SupplierID = so.SupplierID
INNER JOIN  SupplierSubscriptions   ss      ON s.SupplierID = ss.SupplierID
INNER JOIN  shipments               ship    ON ship.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN  Packages                p       ON p.ShipmentID = ship.ShipmentID
WHERE       ss.SubscriptionID = 91
GROUP BY    so.SupplierID, so.supplierName
```